# How to make returned MySQL result into multidimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So far I have accomplished this array

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Test
        [stations] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Name
                        [price] => 50.00
                        [description] => Description
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Name Test
                        [price] => 135.00
                        [description] => Test
                    )
            )
    )
[2]=> Array
    (
        [name] => Test Name
        [stations] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Name
                    [price] => 50.00
                    [description] => Description
                )
    )
```

I do this by using two SQL queries in a nested foreach loop. ID is a POST value :system_

```
$systems = "SELECT * FROM `systems` AS sys WHERE `sys`.`p_id`=:id";
$systemNumber = 0;
$stationNumber = 0;
foreach ($systems as $system) {

        $return[$systemNumber] = array(
            'name' => $system['system_name']
        );
$stations = "SELECT * FROM `stations` WHERE `system_id`=$system[system_id] AND `p_id` = :id";
foreach($stations as $station){
            $stationsArray[$stationNumber] = array(
                'name'=>$station['station_name'],
                'price'=>$station['price'],
                'description'=>$station['description'],
            );

            $return[$systemNumber]['stations'] = $stationsArray;
            $stationNumber++;
        }

        $systemNumber++;
}
```

The problem I have with this is that it is building stations on top of previous array, meaning array becomes something like this

```
...
[stations]=> Array(
  [0]=>...
  [1]=>...
  [2]=>...
  [3]=>...
  [4]=>...
)
```

How can I make that stations will be attached to the corresponding system?

Comment: `$stationsArray = array();` just before `foreach($stations as $station){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the loop.

You are setting variables to 0 outside of the loop

```
$systemNumber = 0;
$stationNumber = 0;
```

however, within the loop, you need to restart both the $stationsArray to nothing and the $stationNumber to 0 aswell, otherwise, when you do

```
foreach($stations as $station){
```

you will keep just increasing the value of the $stationNumber on each loop.

```
$systems = "SELECT * FROM `systems` AS sys WHERE `sys`.`p_id`=:id";
$systemNumber = 0;
$stationNumber = 0;
foreach ($systems as $system) {

        $return[$systemNumber] = array(
            'name' => $system['system_name']
        );
$stations = "SELECT * FROM `stations` WHERE `system_id`=$system[system_id] AND `p_id` = :id";

$stationNumber = 0;
$stationsArray = array();

foreach($stations as $station){
            $stationsArray[$stationNumber] = array(
                'name'=>$station['station_name'],
                'price'=>$station['price'],
                'description'=>$station['description'],
            );

            $return[$systemNumber]['stations'] = $stationsArray;
            $stationNumber++;
        }

        $systemNumber++;
}
```

Comment: You're right. It is working now. I just moved `$stationNumber = 0;` a line down inside `foreach`.